# Multiple select with "none" option

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am building a form that will submit via ajax to a background page. I want to present options as a multiselect control, but with a "None of the Above" option.

The question is, is it possible to make this so that it impossible to select the "None" option AND still select other options? For example:

```
<select id="country" multiple="multiple">
    <option value>None</option>
    <option value="1">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="2">Cuba</option>
    <option value="3">France</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

It would be valid for users to select "None" alone, or "Cuba" and "France" together-- but not "None" and "France". So if a user selected "None" and then anything else, the "None" option would be unselected automatically?

I'm using jQuery in the page if that helps matters.

Comment: I imagine you have a specific requirement in relation to this but...can't you remove "none" option and assume that if no country is selected "none" apply?

Comment: You might also consider a "none of the above" checkbox below the list -- easier for the user and easier to code.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi-- that was the initial implementation-- but users who then selected something had no way to "unselect" it easily, short of making another control / button to clear the input.

Comment: I personally liked the option to add a checkbox below the list for "none".

Comment: I agree that the "none" checkbox is simple, but it's not too elegant and may serve to clutter up the form (since there are multiple selects, for city, province, etc.)

Comment: Have you looked for and considered jQuery/Javascript solutions such as this one? http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange requirements, but anyway this might work for you:

```
$('#country').change(function() {
    if ($('option:first', this).is(':selected')) {
        $('option:not(:first)', this).prop('selected', false);
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zhKKw/

Comment: ic3b3rg is correct, but thanks dfsq for a simple a clean solution!

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/dRVN4/1/

```
  var dropdown = $("#country");
  dropdown.click(function() {
    var val = dropdown.val();
    if (val) {
        var arr = val.toString().split(",");
        if (arr.length > 0 && arr[0] == "") {
            dropdown.val("");
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: It's still possible to select all by pressing Ctrl+A.